# psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)

Tags: python-3.x, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

I am using Virtualbox/ Vagrant on Windows 10 and taking the Udacity Full Stack Developer Course. For some odd reason I cannot connect to the database 'news' via my python code. This is the code I have so far:

```
import psycopg2

DBNAME = "news"

#What are th most popular three articles of all time?


db = psycopg2.connect(dbname=DBNAME, port=5432)  #connects to database
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM articles")
pop_articles = c.fetchall()
pop_articles
db.close()
```

this is the error I keep receiving and it is driving me INSANE:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\tom\Downloads\fsnd-virtual-machine\FSND-Virtual-Machine\vagrant\Trying\logs_analysis1.py", line 10, in <module>
    db = psycopg2.connect(dbname=DBNAME, port=5432)  #connects to database
  File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

[Finished in 2.4s]
```

The strange thing is that I can access the database via gitbash and while within the vagrant directory but I cannot get my python code to return anything without getting this error. The only thing I can think of is that the database is not allowing my code to connect because it is from outside the virtual machine (even though this file is saved in the vagrant directory) and somehow I have to force it to listen on all ports. Unfortunately I do not have the password for postgres so I can't change the configuration to allow this.

Any tips or help would be appreciated. I have been working on this for days.

Comment: So the database is in a Vagrant VM, and the Python script is on the real machine. Correct? When you access the database from within the VM, is it on `localhost:5432` or `0.0.0.0:5432` (or something else)? Have you set up port forwarding on port 5432? (You can see this somewhere under Networking in the VirtualBox setup, and you can configure it in Vagrant but I don't know how.)